# Using #define with the same identifier in many classes lead to "error: <ID> redefined"

Tags: c++, logging, android-ndk, include, header-files

I'm using a helper class to log messages in the android ndk in an easy way. It works like that:

```
LOGE("ClassTag", "Message");
```

Since I don't want to write the tag manually every time I want to log something, I define a TAG constant for every class definition:

```
#define  TAG    "Class1Tag"
```

And then I can just log by doing:

```
LOGE(TAG, "Message");
```

The problem comes up when a class with the defined TAG constant includes another class which has the same TAG constant declared. Then the following compilation error pops up:

```
error: "TAG" redefined
```

How can I take rid of the redefinitions without having to use a different identifier for every #define?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are defining the TAG value in the header file.  For this type of thing to work properly, you should only define it in the implementation file.  Because the implementation file is not included in the other files, there will be no redefinition.

One implication of this is that logging statements can only occur in the implementation file.

Answer (score 1):

Define them in the respective .cpp files instead of in the headers.

Or use a private, static, const `std::string` or array of `char`, which would let you use logging statements in the header while being invisible to other classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the same identifier in several different header files, you are not likely to get the behavior you want.  In a given implementation file, the value for the identifier is going to be *the last one defined*, not necessarily the one associated with the class.  The "last one defined" will be the one in the last header file included in the implementation file, e.g.

a.h:

```
#define TAG "ClassA"
```

b.h:

```
#define TAG "ClassB"
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
```

For this example, uses of TAG in a.cpp will have the value "ClassB".

Basically, you never want to re-define identifiers in your *header* files.  If you define an identifier in an *implementation* file that is the same as one in another *implementation* file, that can work because it won't be visible when compiling the other implementation files.  But the compiler is complaining for a reason, and you should heed what it is telling you to avoid confusion.

EDIT:  I know your compiler is flagging it as an error; the upshot of what I said is don't relax your compiler complaints to accept what you have, because that will probably result in confusion.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `#under TAG` before `#define TAG "ClassTag"`